# Maven-dependency-plugin: overWrite = false ignored

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

My problem is that i want to extract files from a `.jar` file with maven but only if the files do not exist in the output directory. So if i have a file `/src/META-INF/beans.xml` then i only want the `persistence.xml` extracted, etc.

Sadly the maven-plugin irgnores all combinations with `<overWrite>false</overWrite>` that i tried.

**Question**: Any idea what i am doing wrong? Is it possible?

```
<build>
  ...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>unpack</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>unpack</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId> ... </groupId>
              <artifactId> ... </artifactId>
              <version>${project.version}</version>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/META-INF</outputDirectory>
              <includes>beans.xml,persistence.xml</includes>
              <overWrite>false</overWrite>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
          <overWriteIfNewer>false</overWriteIfNewer>
          <overWrite>false</overWrite>
          <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
          <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  ...
</build>
```

Comment: Why do you need to write to `src/META-INF` ? Why no using `src/main/resources/META-INF` and let the resources plugin do it's work ? What kind of purpose is this for?

Comment: I am writing a code generator. The generator is capable of taken handwritten code (and config) into account. The `pom.xml` i have the problem with is for a maven-project which takes a model and generates code from it and then compiles the generated code (while taking into account the hand written code). The generated code is put into `gen/`, the handwritten code is expected to be in `src`. I want to use default-configuration-files if none are given. That is why i want to extract them only if not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple `overWrite` property actually [doesn't exist as a property](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) of the plugin, hence it is simply ignored by the plugin.

Moreover, you are writing to `${basedir}/src/META-INF`, your project, which is probably not the best option, but in some cases could still be reasonable.

You hence want to write it only once, during the `validate` phase of the project and most probably only during the first build: that is, if exists, don't override it again.

for these requirements the following may suit better:

- Use a [Maven profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)
- Use the `activation` option for files `missing`: that is, if the file is not there (first time ever) activate the profile which will execute your plugin configuration; when the file is already there, don't activate the profile, no action obviously won't override anything

  ```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>unpack-files</id>
      <activation>
        <file>
          <missing>${basedir}/src/META-INF/beans.xml</missing>
        </file>
      </activation>
      <build>
         <plugins>
             <!-- move here the maven-dependency-plugin unpack execution -->
         </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  ```

As such you would still have full control of this logic:

- It will be activated when the file is not there, first execution
- It can still be activated on demand, via its `id` (`mvn clean install -Punpack-files`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It kind of solves my problem. I am working on a code-generator that adds files into the /src/ directory if they are not present (they are present if the user chooses to use hand-written files and not the generated ones). If i go with your approach i had to use one profile for each file (because one file can be present and the other one not, i don't wont to overwrite both of them, just add the missing one). Do you know a more elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: @user3637541 did you find a better way? the question still shows up as unanswered in the global list and in general I was curious to know if you got any better solution

Comment: sadly not, i went with your solution.

Comment: In a general description of the plugin this option (`overWrite`) was presented (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html):


    <artifactItem>
      ...
      <overWrite>[ true or false ]</overWrite> # this one
      ...
    </artifactItem>

 and it works fine for me.